# publishing failing in Tomcat v7.0 Server

Tags: tomcat

tomcat does not publishing my project,

HTTP Status 404 - /examples/

type Status report

message /examples/

description The requested resource (/examples/) is not available.

Comment: Please provide some more details like configuration, step's you have done and relevant parts of the logfiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clean the server and clean tomcat work directory[image]